# R - Date and time with if statements

Tags: r, datetime

Based on a condition in the column `geodf$def` of the dataframe `geodf` where the values are 0,1:4 and there are no `NA`, I want to extract time values either from the column `geodf$time` or from the column `geodf$time.stop`. Both time columns are in the format `"%Y%m%d %H%M%S"`.

I tried to solve the problem both with a chain of `ifelse` statements and with a `for` loop, but in both cases I got results in a numeric format (like "1433310096") which I am not able to reconvert on the original format `"%Y%m%d %H%M%S"`.

Here the first attempt with the chain of `ifelse` statements:

```
geodf$start.stop<-ifelse(geodf$def==1,geodf$time,
                              ifelse(geodf$def==2,geodf[row(as.matrix(geodf$time))-1],"time"],
                                     ifelse(geodf$def==3,geodf$time.stop,0)))
```

And here the second attempt with the for loop

```
geodf$start.stop<-0
for (i in 1:length(geodf$time)){
  if(geodf[i,"def"]==1){
    geodf[i,"start.stop"]<-as.Date(geodf[i,"time"], format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
  } else if (geodf[i,"def"]==2){
    geodf[i,"start.stop"]<-as.Date(geodf[i-1,"time"], format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
  } else if (geodf[i,"def"]==3){
    geodf[i,"start.stop"]<-as.Date(geodf[i-1,"time.stop"], format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")}}
```

Furthermore, considered the large size of my dataset, the for loop needs lots of time.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should add some data to the question, your times are converted to numbers somewhere but not knowing the types of the different columns it is hard to tell where.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610 for adding the data.

Comment: BTW: `as.POSIXct(1433310096, origin="1970-01-01")` gives `"2015-06-03 07:41:36 CEST"`.  May help for converting back if you can't avoid the coercion in the first place.

Comment: do `str(geodf)` and give us the result.

Comment: Ok, with `as.POSIXct(1433310096, origin="1970-01-01")` works fine. Thank you all